# Can I get GCC to do partial preprocessing to only add my header files to C file?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm kind of experimenting here. Out university has (quite poorly crafted) homework assignment automatic evaluation system. Currently their system allows only `main.c` file.

I have few debug macros and other things that I consistently use through any simple C code I write. But manually copy pasting them into `main.c` gets annoying.

I googled how to run `gcc` preprocesor over my `c` file.

```
gcc -E main.c -omain_no_header.c
```

This creates file that requires no headers at all. It's necessary to remove now redundant `# xxx` stuf from that file:

```
grep -v '^#' main_no_header.c > main_no_header_clean.c
```

Such file compiles perfectly with this command:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 main_no_header_clean.c -o main
```

No warnings at all. But it contains some quite twisted stuff:

```
 wint_t __attribute__((__cdecl__)) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) _fgetwchar (void);
```

There is also some Windows stuff. This causes lot's of error if I upload this file as an assignment.

So to the question: Can I make GCC create such preprocessed file that will **NOT** have any system libraries unrolled? Specifically, I only want to unroll/embed the files that are within my project (eg. `main.h`, `debug_macros.h` etc).

Of course if this is not an option, I'll have to write a script to do it using regular expressions.

Comment: I feel your pain, my university required use of a highly broken online compiler too. I would suggest actually not using `#include` for your own internal headers in this situation. Instead use a custom notation and use another separate preprocessor to add it. I did something like adding __INCLUDE("Filename") then used a tiny perl script to insert the code before uploading. Fortunately you will likely never have to do this abomination in the real world beyond uni but hopefully it can help for now.